# How does one open a .RTA file?

Tags: files

I got some .rta file from a cellphone. How do I open it? Must it be converted to a txt or other file type first? I am lost. What is this file type? Wiki says it's an Ibm voice to text.

Comment: Could you run `file filename.RTA` on the file in a terminal and update your question with the output? (yes, the `file` command) The "extension" is not relevant in Ubuntu - it's the file headers that *is* interesting.

Comment: It came from a mobile application "Documents".

"Apple binary property list" (from file.. x.rta)

Comment: Please **edit** your question with additional information. It's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum and how this site works.

Comment: From the `file` output my best guess it's an Apple format file. How did you generate this file? What kind of application produced this? An audio recorder? Web browser? And what kind of phone are we talking about? And can you provide this file as a download to share? Please **improve** your question considerably, as it's just shooting in the dark now.

Answer (score 1):

RTA file is an Adobe RoboHelp RTA Data File. RoboHelp is a help authoring tool (HAT) created by eHelp Corporation, acquired by Macromedia, which itself was then acquired by Adobe Systems.

You can use Adobe RoboHelp or other tools, but it seems there's only toos for Windows Or Mac.

You can try a Windows tool through Wine tough.

Read this link for more informatio: http://file.downloadatoz.com/rta-file-extension/

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](http://www.solvusoft.com/no/file-extensions/file-extension-rta/) the *.rta file extension is an **IBM Voice Type Language Vocabels File**, as you also found.

Well, that is one file type that uses *.rta. It could also be a [Adobe RoboHelp file type](http://file.downloadatoz.com/rta-file-extension/).

According to the [Adobe Website](http://www.adobe.com/products/robohelp.edu.html), RoboHelp is a multi-platform publishing tool based on HTML5, which sounds reasonable, since you got the file from a phone.

Thus, opening it would probably require Adobe RoboHelp - on Windows, most likely. You could, however, just give it a shot and try to open it in some other software to see if that results in anything valuable.